# How to distribute Erlang processes (supervisor behaviour)?

Tags: erlang, erlang-otp, erlang-supervisor

I have an Erlang application which runs a supervisor behaviour. Now I want to distribute it across different nodes, meaning that the supervised processes should run on different computers.

Although I read the OTP documentation, I haven't grasped how to configure my app to do this.

Currently, the `.app` file looks like this:

```
{application, my_application,
[{description, "My Description"},
 {vsn, "1"},
 {modules, [my_application, my_supervisor, supervised_process, my_monitor]},
 {registered, [my_supervisor]},
 {applications, [kernel, stdlib]},
 {mod, {my_application,[]}},
 {env, [{file, "/usr/local/log"}]}
]}.
```

If I have two computers running named Erlang VMs, how do I configure the app to run some supervised_processes on both computers?

Answer (score 0):

Once each Erlang VM is running on the same internal network with the same Erlang cookie, you can use the [net_adm](http://erlang.org/doc/man/net_adm.html) module to check that the other node is present and the [rpc](http://erlang.org/doc/man/rpc.html) module to communicate between them.

Here is an example of checking if the other node is responding and sending a synchronous message to it:

```
 Remote = app2@localhost,
 pong = net_adm:ping(Remote),
 ok = rpc:call(Remote, supervised_process, do_something, []).
```

As far as I know you can't have a supervisor on one node supervise processes on another node. You can only control other nodes via messages.

Comment: You can definitely monitor/link processes on other nodes. Whether that's a wise idea is a separate question, given the challenges of knowing what's really happening across a network connection.

Comment: Wow I didn't know that. Guess I should check out the docs for spawn and monitor.

Comment: macintux: but I suppose I cannot rely on the VM to do so transparently, by just configuring the remote nodes. I'd have to access the configuration in the code, right?

Comment: actually in use of OTP supervisor, it is supervisor process who spawns the supervised ones. So it it not question of possibiliy of creating a link, but question of starting and restarting processes on other nodes by supervisor. Would recommend reading thin thread in [mailing list](http://erlang.org/pipermail/erlang-questions/2007-November/031151.html).